# Graphics Producing a Blank Image - Sometimes

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, vb6, handle

I am working on an astronomy application, where I have to display an image from a scientific 16 bit FITs format (monochrome) in a PictureBox. I am interfacing with another DLL that performs some complex astrometry, and also provides a scaled, 8 bit DIB image of the FITS picture (no chioce but to use this dll). It is however written with VB6 in mind, and it will not work with a C# VS2010 Bitmap. The only way I have been able to make this work is to go thru Graphics. The “PaintPicture” is an external dll method that does the conversion. The problem is that this approach often produces a blank image, particularly when in debugging mode:

```
obs.FITSbmp = new Bitmap(obs.p.Columns, obs.p.Rows);
pictureBoxFITS.BackgroundImage = obs.FITSbmp;
obs.g = Graphics.FromImage(obs.FITSbmp); 
//Have to go thru graphics as PP targets VB6
obs.pic.PaintPicture((int)obs.g.GetHdc());
obs.g.ReleaseHdc();
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening, and more importantly, how to fix it? Am I missing something here, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is far far away from my field of expertise but here are some hints that may help:

1. it looks like you (and or the DLL) use GDI.

   - Make sure that all calls are from main application thread.
   - if not then GDI don't work properly sometimes ...
   - the same goes for all visual stuff on desktop/full-screen
2. are you sure that the unconverted bitmap is rendered properly?

   - try to dump it to file before conversion
   - and check it after your problem occur
   - if it is also blank then
   - the problem can be elsewhere

**[Edit1] VCL direct bitmap access** (code in BDS2006 C++ so you must convert *bmp stuff to VB style)

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void bmp_example()
    {
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp;
    int **pyx=NULL,xs=0,ys=0;

    // [init bitmap use]
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;  // new VCL bitmap
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;      // is Device independent to allow direct access
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;   // i use 32 bit to match pixel with int/DWORD variable size

    // here render/load data into bmp
    bmp->Width=2500;             // for example resize bmp to 128x128 pixels
    bmp->Height=2500;

    // create all neded for direct  access
    // must do this after any bitmap realloc/resize
    // main idea is to store pointers into your own variables
    // and access throu them instead of GDI to avoid checking slow-downs
    if (pyx) delete pyx;
    xs=bmp->Width;              // xs,ys = actual bmp size
    ys=bmp->Height;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;      // is Device independent to allow direct access
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;   // i use 32 bit to match pixel with int/DWORD variable size
    pyx=new int*[ys];
    for (int y=0;y<ys;y++)      // copy line pointers to pyx
     pyx[y]=(int*)bmp->ScanLine[y];

    // [direct access]
    int x,y,*p;
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++)          // fill whole bmp
     for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
        {                       // this will fill bmp with grayscale diagonal patern
        pyx[y][x]=((x+y)&255)*0x00010101;
        }
    for (x=0;x<xs;x++)          // does not mater which loop is first
     for (y=0;y<ys;y++)
        {                       // this will fill bmp with grayscale diagonal patern
        pyx[y][x]=((x+y)&255)*0x00010101;
        }
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++)          // this is bit faster (but not by much and limitaccess to lines so y loop must be first)
        {
        p=pyx[y];               // acces just line to avoid 2D addresing
        for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
            {                   // this will clear bmp with white color
            p[x]=0x00FFFFFF;
            }
        }

    // [exit btmap use]
    if (bmp) delete bmp; bmp=NULL;
    if (pyx) delete pyx; pyx=NULL;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- this example 3 times fill **2500x2500 pixel 32bit bitmap ~ 6MP**
- on my machine (Win7 x64 AMD 3.2GHz) is **runtime about 118ms** (compiled as 32bit app)
- **avoid any use of bitmap use pyx,xs,ys instead**
- if this not helps then you can probably have some performance problem in your code
- but without posting it here i just guess
- the best way is to measure the time of your processing steps
- and then you will see where is the slowdown
- I guess some horribly coded loop in histogram
- **do not forget to draw the bitmap onto window before deleting it**
- also you can alloc/delete it on app init/exit and have it in memory the whole time
- any resize,format change (even inside that DLL functions) can reallocate bitmap memory so pyx must be updated after ...

**[Edit2] I have another idea what might be wrong.**

I see that you are accessing piantbox bitmap from your DLL

- paintbox have tendency to update image sometimes when it should not (at least from VCL)
- this can blank your image (I had problems with it before also)
- usually well placed update call sort things out
- or try to create separate bitmap and render it from DLL and then draw it onto paintbox.
- if it is blank and the bitmap not then just draw it again onto paintbox

Comment: Hi Spektre - I think this is the best idea I herad so far, that may explain the erratic behaviour. I have no control of the dll at all, not can I copy its output to the file. Basically, all I can do is call the canned methods, and the rest is a black box. I know it is not optimal, but the manufacturer will not make any changes to help. In reality, 95% of what I use works great, but the image display is important to the user, even if it is of a secondary importance. The only thing I can controll is on my end. Any idea how I can force it in a main thread? I simple example would greatly help. TNX

Comment: if the DLL creates own threads for processing then the answer is no, if you call only blocking functions from DLL (will pause your code until done and then continue) then their calls must be inside your main thread (inside events of your application window like on timer, on button click etc ... or message proc). also you can test if output is blank and if yes then repeat rendering until not if nothing else works out. PS it could be also some incompatibility caused by visual frameworks (.net ... try basic MFC stuff only if it helps)

Comment: I am afraid the DLL creates its own thread, so testing the bmp is probably the best solution at this point. I do get a dynamic array of the values (16bit) and have tried to convert it to the bmp, but it takes too long: First to streach to 8 bits (histogram based) and then SetPixel is way too slow. On a 6MP image it takes an eternity. Know a quick way to make a monochrome image from an byte array? I hate the primitive DLL interfaces, and being locked into it... BTW, thanks a lot for your help and the time.

Comment: Get/Set Pixels is slow (too much checking and conversions) use ScanLine instead (check only once per row) or create an array of line pointers from it so no checking is performed at all. (my software bitmap renders goes up to 70fps for simple meshes so it should be fast enough for single photometry conversions)

Comment: I tried that, but my images are pretty big, like 6MP. Instead, I used Marshal.Copy(pixel_array, 0, data.Scan0, pixel_array.Length). That seemed to be the fastest way to paint the pic. Now it is taking me longer to process the input array. The data is in 16 bit monochrome format, but I only display a portion of it (typically 1000 to 4000), and these parameters depend on the image histogram. Thus, I have to render the byte array to an 8 bit between those values. I am still pondering the fastest way to do this. Right now it is a just couple of "for" loops. Any ideas there?

Comment: i do low-level gfx filtering stuff always myself (it is fastest) but I am not VB friendly (using mostly borland/embarcadero enviroments and C++ language) I will add an edit to answer with my code to access bmp fast so you can see how to do it (convert it to VB accordingly it should not be too difficult)

Comment: Actually, I never use VB - I'm more of a C man (either C# or C++). In this case I have to interface to a DLL meant for VB6 interface. No good wrappers or other friendly stuff. Thus, I have to do lots more creative coding than I'd like to. :(

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean had a lot of issues in the past... Few years ago I decided not to use 3th party stuff and do all myself (for many reasons). After that i have no problem at all. (no compiler update/migration, link, or other problems at all)